# How do you mock useDebounce?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, debouncing

All Mocking attempts create errors:

```
import useDebounce from 'use-debounce'
jest.mock('use-debounce')

TypeError: (0 , _useDebounce.useDebounce) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

trying to target just that mock also fails:

```
jest.mock('use-debounce',() => {
  return {
    useDebounce: jest.fn(value => [value])
  }
})
```

also gives the same error.
using mock timer didn't work either.

Comment: How did you use it?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: It's because you were mixing up the imports. [According to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce) it's indeed used as a **named import**

```
import { useDebounce } from 'use-debounce';
```

So, as long as you import it like ☝️, then you can mock it the way you said:

```
jest.mock('use-debounce',() => {
  return {
    useDebounce: jest.fn(value => [value])
  }
})
```

**PREFER [fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks)**

Keep in mind, an alternative to mocking, which I would highly encourage, is to just use [fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks).

```
import { ComponentThatUsesUseDebounce } from './something';


jest.useFakeTimers(); // <- must appear in your test file


describe('...',() => {

  it('should call a debounce function',() => {
     const thing = render(<ComponentThatUsesUseDebounce/>);
     fireEvent.click(thing.something);
     jest.runAllTimers(); // or runOnlyPendingTimers() or advanceTimersByTime(n)

     expect(something).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

`useDebounce` is not a named export, it's the `default` export:

[Mocking esmodules](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

```
jest.mock('use-debounce',() => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(value => [value])
  }
})
```

Comment: Does not work...
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: (0 , _useDebounce.useDebounce) is not a function or its return value is not iterable]

Comment: @DoryZidon You were importing it wrong in your test file, but please see my full updated answer.